# JS concatenation escaped slashes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to concatenate an url as a background image. My jquery :

```
Img = "http://something.com";
html = '<div class="Img" style="background:url("' + Img + '") no-repeat"></div>';
```

But why the output became like this

```
..style="background:url(" https:="" www-techinasia.netdna-ssl.com="" wp-content="" uploads="" 2014="" 03="" flipkart-720x287.jpg")="" no-repeat"=""..
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using jQuery, I would recommend you to use it to create div.

```
var html = $('<div></div>')
    .addClass('Img')
    .css({
        "background":"url('" + Img + "') no-repeat"
    });
```

However immediate solution is that You need to use quotes properly.

```
html = '<div class="Img" style="background:url(\'' + Img + '\') no-repeat"></div>';
```

```js
var Img = "http://something.com";
var html = '<div class="Img" style="background:url(\'' + Img + '\') no-repeat">Yahooo</div>';

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#a').html(html)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='a'></div>
```